# Java Swing-GUI class does not identify the interface class

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, flowlayout

I am trying to make a simple calculator but i am facing problems when i click on a button. Nothing happens on clicking a button. It is becomming difficult since i cannot detect any problem in the code.

Please help!

PROBLEM- Nothing happens on clicking a button!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Calculator extends JFrame 
{
    Calculate c=new Calculate(this);

    JPanel pan1=new JPanel();
    JTextArea area=new JTextArea(350,150);
    JPanel pan2=new JPanel();
    JButton one=new JButton("1");
    JButton two=new JButton("2");
    JButton three=new JButton("3");
    JButton four=new JButton("4");
    JButton five=new JButton("5");
    JButton six=new JButton("6");
    JButton seven=new JButton("7");
    JButton eight=new JButton("8");
    JButton nine=new JButton("9");
    JButton zero=new JButton("0");
    JButton dot=new JButton(".");
    JButton equals=new JButton("=");
    JPanel pan3=new JPanel();
    JButton del=new JButton("DEL");
    JButton divide=new JButton("/");
    JButton multiply=new JButton("*");
    JButton minus=new JButton("-");
    JButton plus=new JButton("+");
    JPanel pan4=new JPanel();

    public Calculator()
    {
        try {
            // Set System L&F
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        // handle exception
            System.out.println("1");
        }
          catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // handle exception

            System.out.println("2");
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // handle exception

         System.out.println("3");
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // handle exception

            System.out.println("4");
        }
        setTitle("Calculator");
        setSize(350,550);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridLayout bigLayout=new GridLayout(2,1);
        setLayout(bigLayout);

        //Adding ActionListeners
        one.addActionListener(c);
        two.addActionListener(c);
        three.addActionListener(c);
        four.addActionListener(c);
        five.addActionListener(c);
        six.addActionListener(c);
        seven.addActionListener(c);
        eight.addActionListener(c);
        nine.addActionListener(c);
        zero.addActionListener(c);
        plus.addActionListener(c);
        minus.addActionListener(c);
        multiply.addActionListener(c);
        divide.addActionListener(c);
        del.addActionListener(c);
        dot.addActionListener(c);
        equals.addActionListener(c);



        //Adding the text area
        FlowLayout flo=new FlowLayout();
        pan1.setLayout(flo);
        pan1.add(area);
        add(pan1);

        //Adding the numbers
        GridLayout numbersLayout=new GridLayout(4,3);
        pan2.setLayout(numbersLayout);
        pan2.add(seven);
        pan2.add(eight);
        pan2.add(nine);
        pan2.add(four);
        pan2.add(five);
        pan2.add(six);
        pan2.add(one);
        pan2.add(two);
        pan2.add(three);
        pan2.add(dot);
        pan2.add(zero);
        pan2.add(equals);

        //Adding the  operations
        GridLayout operationsLayout=new GridLayout(5,1);
        pan3.setLayout(operationsLayout);
        pan3.add(del);
        pan3.add(divide);
        pan3.add(multiply);
        pan3.add(minus);
        pan3.add(plus);

        //Adding the keypad
        GridLayout keypadLayout=new GridLayout(1,2);
        pan4.setLayout(keypadLayout);
        pan4.add(pan2);
        pan4.add(pan3);
        add(pan4);

        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        Calculator cal=new Calculator();
    }
}
```

and here is the interface class which is, right now, used to display the text on the JTextArea area.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculate implements ActionListener{

    Calculator gui;
    public Calculate(Calculator in)
    {
        gui=in;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String enterString;
        enterString=event.getActionCommand();
        gui.area.setText(enterString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you put debug into `actionPerformed` and verified that the method is called and that `getActionCommand` returns what you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Your code works, but you don’t see its result due to your use of `FlowLayout`. Consider that the size you have passed to the `JTextArea` constructor is in *characters*, not in pixels. Therefore, it doesn’t fit into the visible area but the `FlowLayout`doesn’t adjust its size.

Change the creation code to `new JTextArea(15,30)` and you will see your updates. However, the better choice would be not to specify a fixed size but change the layout to something that adjusts the text area to the available size.

E.g. change the construction to `new JTextArea()` and the code

```
    //Adding the text area
    FlowLayout flo=new FlowLayout();
    pan1.setLayout(flo);
    pan1.add(area);
    add(pan1);
```

to

```
    //Adding the text area
    add(area);
```

Comment: Thank you . The code is working now because of the above mentioned changes.